# Would Postgres data base break if I change a model field name? (heroku)

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Feels like a silly question, but I cannot seem to find an answer.

I have a number of changes that I need to migrate.

Amongst those changes, I have a model field name that has been changed.

On local, Django worked out the model field just changed name (simply asked confirmation that old field = new field). I know Postgres and Heroku sometimes behave differently.

I left the code below, it's quite simple but the possibility to lose the database worries me.

Below is what the local migration look like on local

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0085_modelname_timeframe'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='modelename',
            old_name='timestamp',
            new_name='created_at',
        ),
    ]
```

and this is the **model.py**

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Does Heroku work out field name changes easily, or is it something to avoid?

Comment: "I know Postgres and Heroku sometimes behave differently"—comparing Postgres and Heroku is like comparing a watermelon and a giraffe. They are completely different things. Heroku does have a Postgres service, but it's just Postgres. Not sure what you mean by "sometimes behave differently" if that's the comparison you're trying to make.

Comment: I meant heroku/postgres vs Django run locally (which runs on SQLite)

Comment: There should be **zero** issues, just commit with that migration file you made for your local Sqlite and it'll work exactly the same on postgres. I do it all the time, but no Heroku, I use uWsgi instead.

Comment: Oh, Postgres vs. SQLite is completely different. They're both fantastic databases, but are _not_ feature-equivalent. Pick one and use it in each of your environments. If you intend to deploy to Heroku, that means you need to switch to Postgres in development. Don't develop with one database and use another in production. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Developing for SQLite and trying to run production on PostgreSQL, is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Following the general advice I decide to spend some to move to Postgres on local. Was worried it would be complicated by It was easier than I thought.